# Managing Sessions in node

Tags: node.js, session

I'm learning how to use nodejs and i'm developing a chat page with my experience from php, i know that nodejs does almost nothing about what php does, so i'm building the whole structure, like rebuilding the php engine but just in node, for now im having problems with sessions, because i want to make a User system, so im making a login, it's quite hard for me to figure out what process to do in order to make a login process and if user exist, make the session, i have this code in my index

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login - Chat</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="page">

        <h2>Chat Login</h2>

        <div id="login-form" class="well">
            <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <div class="form-group" method="post">
                    <label for="Username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = init;

    var socketio = io.connect(window.location.hostname);

    function init()
    {
        var login = document.getElementById('login-form');

        login.onsubmit = requestData;
    }

    function requestData()
    {
        username = document.getElementById('Username');
        password = document.getElementById('Password');

        //alert if form is empty.
        if((username.value && password.value) == '')
        {
            alert('Box has empty value.');

            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            socketio.emit('Login_user', {user: username.value, pass: password.value});
        }
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

im using socket.io for transfering data from client to server and viceversa (im still learning it socket). I got stuck right in this step, i just need to know how to handle sessions in nodejs, i've got my github repository for this : [Chat](https://github.com/Nosthertus/nodejs_Chat) so you can see my whole code in there, any idea how to handle sessions?.

PD: I'm just a newbie developer, i have like 6 months using PHP and like 2 weeks with node, i dont want to use any framework in order to learn the language better.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Express.js as node framework. Express has built in support via Connect framework. Im using this via a Redis backed session store to allow multi server load balancing. Here's a snippet on node-express-connect work in app.js if you want:

```
var express = require('express')
    , RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express)
    ;

var app = express();

app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'some pass',
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge:null,
    domain:'.yourdomain.com'
  },
  store: new RedisStore({
    ttl:1800, //30 min redis ttl
    client:redis,
    secret:'some pass'
  })
}));
```

Comment: well, i was planning to do this session and cooking stuff without any framework so i can learn how it is really done, i am going to keep this suggestion in mind, and thank you for sharing your snippet.

Comment: do you have any book or guide tutorial for this framework?. i'm also learning javascript, so i'm doing this slow

Comment: sadly no real books, but it's pretty much a drop-in, you are all hands off once it's in place. This one is good: http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Since your using socket.io, I would recommend reading through the session.socket.io module. The source code is very small and readable:

- [README.md](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io#readme)
- [session.socket.io.js](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io/blob/master/session.socket.io.js) (48 lines of code)